# Adding a click event to an element?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

How can one assign a click event to an arbitrary span (`eg. &lt;span id="foo">foo&lt;/span>`) in an ST2 app?

I have a trivial example that illustrates the idea of what I'd like to do.  In the example, I write the letters `A,B,C` and I'd like to tell the user which letter they clicked.

Here's an image:

[image]

---

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({

    launch: function() {
        var view = Ext.create('Ext.Container', {

            layout: {
                type: 'vbox'
            },
            items: [{
                html: '&lt;span id="let_a">A&lt;/span>  &lt;span id="let_b">B&lt;/span> &lt;span style="float:right" id="let_c">C&lt;/span>',
                style: 'background-color: #c9c9c9;font-size: 48px;',
                flex: 1
            }]
        });
        Ext.Viewport.add(view);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to do it if you have multiple custom components that have unique ids? I have thumbnails with unique ids from my store that I am trying to pass to a popup. Surely I wouldn't want to have multiple listeners for each thumbnail id?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can add a listener to a specific element using delegation. It is actually fairly simply to use.

```
Ext.Viewport.add({
    html: 'test <span class="one">one</span> hmmm <span class="two">two</span>',
    listeners: [
        {
            element: 'element',
            delegate: 'span.one',
            event: 'tap',
            fn: function() {
                console.log('One!');
            }
        },
        {
            element: 'element',
            delegate: 'span.two',
            event: 'tap',
            fn: function() {
                console.log('Two!');
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

The main parts are `element` and `delegate`.

- `element` will have the value of `element` in almost every case, unless you are working with custom components with custom templates.
- `delegate` is a simple CSS selector. So it could be anything from `span` to `span .test.second`

Ideally, as **Thiem** said, you should take advantage of components as much as possible. They will give you much more flexibility. But I know there are definitely some cases where you need to do this. There will be no performance implications; in fact, it will be faster than using components. However, you should **never** implement listeners the way he suggested. It will not be performant and is extremely dirty (as he mentioned).

Comment: Can I handle multiple <span>'s in the same html: like in my example?

Comment: Fantastic - thank you for this answer. Sencha's docs could use more examples of using Ext/Touch's abilities outside of the standard model presented in their components and controls.

Comment: @rdougan can we use id instead of class because my class is dynamic  and i tried span.id it didn't worked for me

Comment: @rdougan how can i pass value on listeners from span.

Comment: @sur007 the first argument passed when the listener `fn` is called is the event. That Object has a target property which is the span clicked.

Comment: @rdougan thanks i solved it but i am having problem to pass value from click event. These values comes from tpl dynamically

Comment: Thanks a lot @rdougan. It's a shame for Sencha that one must dig up some year-old comments from some site to find such important information about their API.