# Add controls to detailview

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm new to Sencha Touch 2. Found lots of examples of lists/nested lists that lead to a detailview. But what if you want to put controls on the detail card to manipulate the data represented by that list item?

For instance, imagine a list of recipes. Then tapping on a recipe would reveal details about that recipe, etc.  But the view could also rate the recipe on a couple of dimensions, e.g. with a couple of sliders and a "Submit ratings" button.

How can this be accomplished in Sencha Touch 2? It seems like you can create an html template for the detailview, but they just fold in data from the datastore tied to the nested list, without actually providing controls.

Any pointers or examples highly appreciated. TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically this consists of 2 steps:

- Define your custom `itemTpl` which has your additional controls such as buttons, checkboxes, etc. using **HTML** code, for example:

`itemTpl: '<div>{title} <input id="anId" class="aClass" readonly value="{buttonControlName}"></div>'`

- Add handling functions for your created html controls. Here is a good answer:

[Adding a click event to an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298683/adding-a-click-event-to-an-element/10306635#10306635)

Comment: Thank you, that's helpful. But what if  you want to use Sencha controls in your detailview, like the sliders (http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.0.2/#!/api/Ext.field.Slider)? I hope it's not necessary to recreate the slider in raw html, that sort of defeats the purpose.

Comment: Yes it's possible, too. But you will have to master the methodology of magic methods in sencha touch. Please refer to this link: https://www.sencha.com/blog/dive-into-dataview-with-sencha-touch-2-beta-2